# A site getting 'too many redirects' response on curl but works fine in a browser (chrome)

Tags: bash, google-chrome, curl, redirection, infinite-loop

I have a case when a URL opens fine in a browser but generates 'too many redirects' in `curl`.

As an example below, a request using curl from my WSL2 instance which was taken from a bash script:

```
curl -sSL  https://www.bricomarche.net -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code} %{url_effective} \n"

curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
302 https://intermarche.queue-it.net/?c=intermarche&e=bricoprodkuserv2&ver=v3-java-3.5.1&cver=45&cid=fr-CA&l=BRICOMARCHE&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bricomarche.com%2F
```

Note, I omitted in the command above the custom user-agent which was copied from my Chrome browser for simplicity. The result is the same.

But, if I try to open the above URL in my Chrome browser - it works fine.

The same situation I got with URL `https://shop.mercury.co.nz` - opens fine in the browser, but getting too many redirects in curl:

```
$  curl -sSL https://shop.mercury.co.nz -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code} %{url_effective} \n"
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed     
302 https://shop.mercury.co.nz/nz/join/prepare
```

Any idea how to fix the curl?

Comment: Cookies? Your curl command is not handling cookies, but your browser will.  Maybe the site sets a cookie, redirects, and then looks for that cookie.  If there's no cookie, it redirects back to start again?

Comment: Yes, seems cookies are the problem....

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is a cookie issue at least for some cases.

Adding `-b non-existing` as a parameter to curl request somehow helps to fix the problem.

```
curl -sLI -b non-existing https://the_site -o /dev/null -w "%{response_code} %{url_effective} \n"
```